# Automated process to Update data definition comments in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, comments, metadata

I am trying to create an automated process to update data definition comments for a database in Oracle. Does anyone have prior experience on a specific stored procedure that could be used to automatically update column information after a load? I am trying to use a variable because we cannot be hard coding this comment information as it defeats the purpose of the automation. Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do. Are you talking about table and column comments? (which are usually used to describe what kind of data is stored in a table or column) And are you updating these after every data load? Maybe give a couple of examples to explain.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the table and column comments which will be updated after each load. Currently, you have to manually enter each string value (i.e: COMMENT ON COLUMN employees.job_id 
                   IS 'abbreviated job title';)                                
There are over 30,000 comments that need to be updated and therefore we need to create an automated process to achieve this.

Comment: "the table and column comments which will be updated after each load".
What kind of load are you talking about? The reason I was asking you to provide examples is because usually table and column comments are not updated after data loads. They are created at design time to describe what the table does and what business functionality it provides. Once created, they should usually only change if the description for the column changes.

Comment: This is necessary now because the initial design was designed poorly. Therefore, this problem is now present.

Answer (score 0):

WHilst I don't understand the need to do this, you could try generating this and running as dynamic SQL. Assuming the list of tables and columns and teh comments follow some rules:

```
SET SERVEROPUTPUT ON
SPOOL colcomm.sql
DECLARE
       CURSOR c1 IS
          SELECT table_name, column_name
          FROM    user_tab_columns
          WHERE   table_name like 'fred%';
       vCmd VARCHAR2(500);
    BEGIN
       FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
          vCmd := 'COMMENT ON COLUMN ' || r1.table_name || '.' || r1.column_name || ' IS ''' || '????' || '''';
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( vCmd );
       END LOOP;
    END;
```

Run this, spool to a file, then run the spool file.

You can use other mechanisms like UTL_FILE is the output is too big, but I hope the above gives you an idea.

I haven't tried running this through "EXECUTE vCmd" to see if that would work, if so you would not need the spool.

Issue I see is, how do you know what you want to set the column comments to?